# How to cancel jobs in DependencyNeverSatisfied

Tags: slurm

I'd like to clean up the queue and remove pending jobs with the status *DependencyNeverSatisfied*.

Instead of executing *scancel* for each job ID in that status, I was wondering if there exists any option that allows it to do in batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to address this with a Bash one-liner. One possible solution is:

```
squeue -h -t PD -O jobid,reason | awk '/DependencyNeverSatisfied/ {print $1}' | xargs scancel
```

The `squeue` command is run with the `-h` option to remove headers, `-t` option to filter out jobs that are not in a PENDING state, and `-O` is used to show only the job id and the reason. The list is fed to `awk` that print job ids of those jobs that are pending for the "DependencyNeverSatisfied" reason, and then fed to `xargs` to call `scancel` on those job ids.

As a sanity check you can insert an `echo` to see what would be executed rather than actually executing it:

```
squeue -h  -t PD -O jobid,reason | awk '/DependencyNeverSatisfied/ {print $1}' | xargs echo scancel
```

Comment: With the -O option did not work. Without, it works like a charm, though.

Comment: The `-o jobid,reason` option doesn't works for me, but either `-O jobid,reason` or `-o "%F %r"` works.

Comment: `-O jobid,reason` had truncated output for me, so I used `-o "%F %r"`